# Is there a fluid that visually displays electrical voltage/current?

Tags: voltage, current-measurement, high-voltage, voltage-measurement, water

I have a device that subjects fluid in a cuvette to a DC voltage waveform for a few seconds.  The device is pretty powerful (lots of capacitors), able to continuously deliver up to 1,000 Vdc @ 40 A through the cuvette.

I am looking for a fluid to use in testing that:

- Visually indicates when subjected to voltage or current

  - Note: electrolysis bubbling or temperature change isn't good enough
  - Ideal: fluid shimmers, sparkles, or changes color
- Impedance somewhat resembles that of water
- Nice-to-have: multi-use

  - Can be zapped multiple times with the same visual response

Are there fluids out there which possess these properties?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display ... ?

Comment: Voltage or current or power implies resistance and heat up to  40kW for what purpose?

Comment: How about reduction of colored bacteria infected fluids ?  https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32713960/

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I didn't include in the OP to avoid influencing the answers, but the use case is [Electroporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroporation)

Comment: I think there is a better way, and that is to measure the impedance of the load with an RLC meter capacitance at 100k to 1MHz then source impedance and measure the power transfer regulated or preset with capacitance to make an impedance power limiter and with a 100 mV current sensor measure the impulse power with voltage product. Also measure Partial Discharge with CW as ionic salts may discharge. I have done this for diffusion welding up to 10kA 4V with forced water cooling to regulate the power transfer in a continuously variable process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

water containing universal indicator will change colour at each electrode.[image]